# Is it possible to add a reference to an existing application

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I am using WinForms and MS Access to develop a solution. During the planning stages it has become clear that there are actually three separate apps, two main apps, and one smaller app that will be used to maintain and store some data which is then used by the other two.

Rather than the just access the common data from the main apps by querying the smaller app's database I was thinking about exposing methods via an interface in the smaller app that can then be used by the larger ones, kinda like an api.

My question is, is this possible? Maybe by adding a reference to an already deployed app? Are there any best practices around this, what would happen if a new version of the smaller app is deployed, would that break the reference?

I've done some research on this but can only find info related to web services or creating common library dlls / frameworks which is something I'm familiar with, but I think this is a slightly different scenario.

I'd very much appreciate any guidance / advice,

Cheers,

Jamie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you should create library inseted app for common using. Then this is library can be added as reference to any application.

Comment: It's definitely better design to use a library, but .NET does in no way prevent that you link an exe as if it was a dll.

Comment: I don't suggest to link app to dll, i suggested to link dll to app.

Comment: So create a separate dll that provides an interface to the smaller app which is then added as a reference in the larger apps? What advantage does this have over simply adding a reference to the smaller app in the larger app?

Comment: well for one it means that the larger app doesn't have to load into memory all of the non-important stuff from the smaller app just to access come common functions. It can load just a dll containing the functions it is interested in. It also means that you cannot update the smaller app without breaking the larger app. Effectively, it means the larger app can ignore the existence of the smaller app because its really interested in a set of functions that just so happen to be also used by a smaller second app.

Comment: Ah, so regardless of the approach, if I update the smaller app, I always end up breaking the larger app? I either end up breaking the link between the smaller app and the larger one, or the link between the smaller app and the intermediary dll?

Comment: Yes, if you change smaller app, as you called it, then you should recomile and the larger app, because there is possible runtime errors. Usually, solution includes common library and the app wich used this library. When you recompile you solution, you always recompile the both: the library and the app. As result - you app always used the correct version of the library.