# Keeping the api inside or outside a vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, api

I have inherited a vb.net application at work which is written in procedural code. As I work on the app I am planning on moving it towards an OO-architecture.

In addition, we have some needs within the company to use the data from this app in other places. One existing way we've done this is to write Perl scripts that access the underlying MySQL database directly. As a result, there has been much logic duplication, because the scripts can't access all the business rules that live inside the vb.net app.

Most of my experience is in web development, so when I first came across this problem the first solution that came to mind was to build a REST api to serve up the data over HTTP and which contained the business logic, and then to build the vb.net app as a client of this api. Then, external scripts could also consume the api without duplication of effort.

I don't have any experience with vb.net, and because of the way the app is currently structured this would require lots of work. Another possibility I thought of was creating the api within the vb.net app and somehow exposing it to the outside world (in addition to the GUI layer of the vb.net app itself).

I'm also aware that my analogy to the web world may not hold up, just because I'm so unfamiliar with desktop development.

Can anybody share any wisdom or guidance here? The project is going to be a big one either way, and I'm just trying to figure out the best path forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was wondering a similar thing with an app I'm currently building and asked a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586214/is-it-possible-to-add-a-reference-to-an-existing-application the consensus seems to be to extract the common functionality (methods the provide access to your db for e.g.) into a separate dll which can then be added as a reference to your main VB.net app, and any other app you want. I'm still not sure about the final answer I received and so am pretty interested to see what answers you get :)

Comment: Break out any the sevices to the application using WEB APInis a good idea. But some believe ita best to start finding all the depencies and creating abstractions for them. Once that is done using services is trivial and it will go a long way to cleaning up the code.

Comment: Interesting, thanks guys! I'll keep this answer updated with anything else I find.